# How to unit test a function that does not return anything using jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

How to unit test a function that does not return anything using jasmine.

Below is my sample function

```
    function fixRightRefinementpanel() {
    var refinementWidth = (($(".navmenu").width() * 0.25) - 15);
    $(".refinement-section-right").css("position", "fixed").css("width", refinementWidth);
}
```

Comment: i could not find a tag for jasmine

Comment: There is not a Jasmine tag for a reason, this is a SharePoint board. Go ask your question in the proper place

Comment: i have used jasmine to test my client side code JavaScript which i am using in SharePoint.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SharePoint technology. The global StackOverflow has a jasmine tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmine You are much more likely to get answers there; actually if you search ``void function`` there, you get 56 answers